# Displaying work space in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio

While I were reading something on the internet, I saw something about C#. It looks like a work space in matlab. It includes variables, structures etc. I posted it below.

[image]

How can I display this work space in C# Visual Studio? It may be a simple question but I don't know the way.

Comment: This is the "Locals" window in Visual Studio. You can access it (from within an instance of Visual Studio that's currently debugging a running application) by going to `Debug->Windows->Locals`.

Comment: Note there's not really a "C# Visual Studio". Visual Studio is VS, regardless of the language you're using. The Locals windows is not C# specific.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Visual Studio while you are debugging: `Debug (Menu) --> Windows --> Locals`

That will display the "Locals" tab which shows you the values of variables in your local scope.

Your picture also shows the "Watch" tab which is useful for watching any variable (or even a calculation using any variable).  Access that from `Debug --> Windows --> Watch --> Watch [1,2,3, or 4]`.